# Is there a better way to avoid angular-maps relocating my map marker when the map is moved?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

So I'm using the (awesome) angular-ui:angular-google-maps for displaying a map.  Having to fix some things by a previous coder, but mostly it's quite awesome.

One issue has come up that has me annoyed, because it seems like the solution should be easy -- this *cannot* be an unusual use case!

I have an object.  Most of it's data structure is irrelevant, but it has a geolocation attached.  So when I set up the map (skipping a few things for brevity...

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='ctrl.object.location'>
    <ui-gmap-marker coords ='ctrl.object.location'>
    </uigmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Everything looks great.  Then, when I try to move the map...  the marker stays in the center as the map moves.  *Angular Google Maps is updating my objects coordinates as the map moves*.  And, as a result, naturally the marker moves to -- they're both references, not copies, of the same object.

To 'fix' this, I've written a small function that returns a cached value if possible, only returning a new value if the object doesn't have that second, 'cached' value on it.  It works, but... it's cludgy.  There has to be a better approach for this!

Comment: You could disable the dragging or point to a copy of the model's location `angular.copy(ctrl.object.location)` in your coords attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using same object reference for map center and marker.

Thus as you drag map the internals are updating the coordinates of the object as center but it is also used as marker so marker is staying in center

Just make a separate object for `center`

```
this.mapCenter = angular.copy(this.object.location);
```

View

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='ctrl.mapCenter'>
    <ui-gmap-marker coords ='ctrl.object.location'>
    </uigmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: I understand the _problem_.  You're just re-iterating the exact solution I came up with.  The issue was finding a better solution than caching a copy of the address.  It's cludgy, at best, since I have to do it in a method.  (The base object updates reactively)

Comment: Don't see why it's cludgy when using same object for 2 different use cases is more cludgy

Comment: I think we have a communications breakdown.  Not sure where it is.  My version of the solution is, simply, to take Foo.location and cache it to Foo.locationCache to provide a second copy.  If locationCache exists, use that; otherwise, set it *then* return it.